# Why can't pipes be overwritten the same way as variables?

Tags: c, unix, io, pipe, system-calls

I am trying to write a simple program in C where some content is passed through a pipe to a child process twice, each time with a different value:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define READ  0
#define WRITE 1

int main(){
    int myPipe[2];
    if (pipe(myPipe) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe Error!");
        return -1;
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        perror("Error forking!");       
    else if(pid > 0){
    // Master
        char var[4];

        // Sends the first value.
        sprintf(var, "foo");
        close(myPipe[READ]);
        write(myPipe[WRITE], var, sizeof(var));
        close(myPipe[WRITE]);

        // Sends the second value.
        sprintf(var, "bar");
        close(myPipe[READ]);
        write(myPipe[WRITE], var, sizeof(var));
        close(myPipe[WRITE]);

        wait(NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pid == 0){ // Child
        char received[4];

        // Reads the first value.
        close(myPipe[WRITE]);
        read(myPipe[READ], received, sizeof(received));
        close(myPipe[READ]);
        printf("I have received the following value: %s\n", received);

        // Reads the second value.
        close(myPipe[WRITE]);
        read(myPipe[READ], received, sizeof(received));
        close(myPipe[READ]);
        printf("I have received the following value: %s\n", received);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Seems, though, the output is not the expected, as variable `received` never changes its value:

```
I have received the following value: foo
I have received the following value: foo
```

...when the desired output is:

```
I have received the following value: foo
I have received the following value: bar
```

I can't understand why this happens, as I think - probably wrongly - pipes get overwritten every time they are used the same way you can perform:

```
int i = 0;
printf("%i\n", i);
i = 4;
printf("%i", i);
```

...which would return:

```
0
4
```

Why isn't this phenomenon happening in pipes?

Comment: It seems that the parent is even closing the writing end of the pipe before sending `bar`.

Comment: You cannot use a pipe after you have closed it.

Comment: You're not checking the return values of the write or read calls. Do yourself a favor and check _all_ your syscalls before doing anything else.

Comment: Do not `close` pipe if you want to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why isn't this phenomenon happening in pipes?

You are calling `close()` more than you should.

The parent process is closing the *writing end* of the pipe before the second write (i.e: "bar"). The child process is closing the *reading end* of the pipe before the second read. Therefore, your second read in the child process is actually not reading anything from the pipe, since the *file descriptor* passed to `read()` is not valid. Note that, the second `write()` in the parent process didn't succeed either for the same reason.

Besides, pipe ends that have been already closed are being closed again: the *reading end* in the parent and the *writing end* in the child.

---

By just removing those inconvenient calls to `close()`, the code produces exactly what you are expecting :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define READ  0
#define WRITE 1

int main(){
    int myPipe[2];
    if (pipe(myPipe) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Pipe Error!");
        return -1;
    }
    pid_t pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        perror("Error forking!");       
    else if(pid > 0){
    // Master
        char var[4];

        // Sends the first value.
        sprintf(var, "foo");
        close(myPipe[READ]);
        write(myPipe[WRITE], var, sizeof(var));

        // Sends the second value.
        sprintf(var, "bar");
        write(myPipe[WRITE], var, sizeof(var));
        close(myPipe[WRITE]);

        wait(NULL);
        return 0;
    }
    else if (pid == 0){ // Child
        char received[4];

        // Reads the first value.
        close(myPipe[WRITE]);
        read(myPipe[READ], received, sizeof(received));
        printf("I have received the following value: %s\n", received);

        // Reads the second value.
        read(myPipe[READ], received, sizeof(received));
        printf("I have received the following value: %s\n", received);
        return 0;
    }

  return 0;
}
```

That is, the output is:

```
I have received the following value: foo
I have received the following value: bar
```

Comment: Nice detail! I forgot to return a value at the end of the `main` function.

Comment: I think you need `#include <sys/types.h>` too for =>> `pid_t`

Comment: @Michi I didn't get any error. I think that header should be already included in `unistd.h`, since it has the prototype of `fork()` which returns `pid_t`.

Comment: @水飲み鳥 It is possible, but on my System (Linux mint 18.2 with gcc 7) [I get This](https://pastebin.com/raw/uAerWxn5)

Comment: [The manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Identification.html) says it should both included. `unistd.h` and `sys/types.h`